# Undefined properties in array split

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

So, I have this here function designed to split the array elements and return them to two separate arrays. Problem is, when I try yo run it it returns
"Challenges.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')"
I don't really get it, what am I missing here? Sorry for the noob question, been studying for less than two weeks :D

```
const array0 = [
    "3:1",
    ...
    "4:0",
  ];
let array1 = [];
let array2 = [];

for (let i = 0; i <= array0.length; i++) {
    array1.push(array0[i].split(":")[0]);
    array2.push(array0[i].split(":")[1]);
  }
  
  console.log(array1, array2);
```

Answer (score 4):

The condition of for loop should be `i < array0.length` instead of `i <= array0.length`

Answer (score 2):

your for loop is wrong, it should be

```js
for (let i = 0; i < array0.length; i++) {

}
```

and not

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= array0.length; i++) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change that `<=` to `<` or add `-1` after `array0.length`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < array0.length; i++) {
    array1.push(array0[i].split(":")[0]);
    array2.push(array0[i].split(":")[1]);
  }
```

both ok

```
for (let i = 0; i < array0.length -1; i++) {
    array1.push(array0[i].split(":")[0]);
    array2.push(array0[i].split(":")[1]);
  }
```

Comment: Removed the = and we good :D best of the day to you mate!